# Big O complexity in algorithms

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I want to order the terms  such that each one is big-O of next one

√n√logn

√n log⁡( n^30)

n/〖(logn)〗^2

〖16〗^(log√n)

Can anyone help in  finding order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Comment: (This question has been edited to the point of invalidating some of the answers.)

Answer (score 2):

Claim: `16*log(sqrt(n))` is in `O(n/(log(n))^2)`.

By the definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), `f(x)` is in `O(g(x))` iff `lim sup abs(f(x)/g(x)) < infinity` for n approaching infinity. If the limit exists, lim sup becomes lim, and using the rule of l'Hospital (assuming the preconditions are fulfilled, see [Wikiepdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)), we have:

```
lim abs(f(x)/g(x)) = lim ((8*log(n))/n) * log(n) * log(n)
= lim (8*(log(n))^3)/n = lim (24*(log(n))^2)/n 
= lim (48*log(n))/(n^2) = lim (24/n^3) = 0
```

Here, I applied the rule of l'Hopstial three times to get rid of (log(n))^3. Hence, the lim exists and is, thus, equal to lim sup and by definition the claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the following four functions:

1. `(n*log(n))^(1/2)`
2. `n^(1/2)*log⁡(n^30) = 30*n^(1/2)*log(n)`
3. `n/log(n)^2`
4. `16*log(n^(1/2)) = 8*log(n)`

and you want to understand why `8*log(n) = O(n/log(n)^2)`.

(The following is not intended to be fully rigorous, but just provide some intuition by this is true.)

---

Intuitively, you can start by showing that `log(n) = O(n^(1/k))` for any constant `k>0`. This means that `log(n)^2 = O(n^(1/k))` as well, since squaring both sides of the inequality `log n < n^(1/k)` yields `log(n)^2 < n^(2/k)`, and `2/k` is still a constant.

Next, consider the equality `n^(1/2) == n/n^(1/2)`. What happens if you use a smaller root, say the cube root? On the left-hand side, you have a function that grows more slowly. On the right, the ratio grows more *quickly*, because you are dividing by something "smaller", so that sufficiently large `n`, `n^(1/3) < n/n^(1/3)`. This is true for larger constants `k` as well, so in general `n^(1/k) = O(n/n^(1/k)`

Finally, we'll do a bit of handwaving and note that since `log(n)^2` grows even *more* slowly than any root, you can say the following:

```
log(n)^2 = O(n^(1/k)) = O(n/n^(1/k)) = O(n/log(n)^2)
```

Multiplying everything by the constant 8 isn't going to affect the above chain, so we can finally conclude (non-rigorously) that

```
8*log(n)^2 = O(n/log(n)^2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you understand calculus, you can perform following check:

1) limit (№ 2 / №1) = (should be infinity)

2) limit (№ 3 / №2) = (should be infinity)

3) limit (№ 4 / №3) = (should be infinity)

where № i - i-th expression

Answer (score 0):

The intuition behind `n` being greater than `log n` is pretty clear, so let's get rigorous about it.

```
  limit n->infinity (16 log(sqrt(n))/(n / (log n)^2)
= limit n->infinity  8 (log n)^3 / n = 0
```

If we prove the last equality, the order follows. We can use [l'Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)'s rule repeatedly to get:

```
  limit n->infinity  8 (log n)^3 / n
= limit n->infinity  24 (log n)^2 / n
= limit n->infinity  48 (log n) / n
= limit n->infinity  48 / n = 0
```

Comment: I want to know that the above-mentioned order for big O is right or not. if not can anyone help me in finding correct order